# Uploading Multiple files from Angular JS to SQL DB using MVC Web API

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="messageBoardApp" class="page-header">

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="../libs/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!--<script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="../libs/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../libs/angular-file-upload.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../libs/console-sham.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="MessageBoardModule.js"></script>
        <script src="MessageBoardController.js"></script>
        <script src="MessageBoardService.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="messageBoardController" class="container">
        <div>
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" id="titleText" ng-model="message.title" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="content">Content</label>
                    <textarea name="contentText" ng-model="message.content" rows="5" cols="40" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="file">File</label>
                    <input type="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" multiple>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fileList">These are your selected files</label>
                    <br/>
                    <ul>
                        <select name="files" ng-model="selectedFile" ng-options="option.file.name for option in uploader.queue" size="4" class="form-control"></select>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-6">
                    <input type="button" value="Remove File" ng-click="remove()" />
                    <button ng-click="uploader.clearQueue()" ng-disabled="!uploader.queue.length">Remove all</button>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-6">
                    <button ng-click="uploader.uploadAll()">Upload All</button>
                    <!--<input type="submit" value="Add Message" ng-click="submitForm()"/>-->
                    <input type="button" value="Exit" ng-click="Close()" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
messageBoardApp.controller('messageBoardController', ['$scope', 'FileUploader', 'MessageBoardService',
    function ($scope, FileUploader, MessageBoardService) {
        var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({});

        $scope.remove = function (selectedItem) {
            $scope.uploader.queue.splice(uploader.queue.indexOf(selectedItem), 1);
        };
        //$scope.message=messageBoardService.SaveMessage();
        $scope.submitForm = function () {
            alert("Controller");
            var message = $scope.message;
            MessageBoardService.SaveMessage(message);
            //MessageBoardService.SaveMessage($scope.message);
        };
        // FILTERS
        uploader.filters.push({
            name: 'customFilter',
            fn: function (item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
                return this.queue.length < 10;
            }
        });
        // CALLBACKS
        uploader.onWhenAddingFileFailed = function (item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, filter, options) {
            console.info('onWhenAddingFileFailed', item, filter, options);
        };
        uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function (fileItem) {
            console.info('onAfterAddingFile', fileItem);
        };
        uploader.onAfterAddingAll = function (addedFileItems) {
            console.info('onAfterAddingAll', addedFileItems);
        };
        uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function (item) {
            console.info('onBeforeUploadItem', item);
        };
        uploader.onProgressItem = function (fileItem, progress) {
            console.info('onProgressItem', fileItem, progress);
        };
        uploader.onProgressAll = function (progress) {
            console.info('onProgressAll', progress);
        };
        uploader.onSuccessItem = function (fileItem, response, status, headers) {
            console.info('onSuccessItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
        };
        uploader.onErrorItem = function (fileItem, response, status, headers) {
            console.info('onErrorItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
        };
        uploader.onCancelItem = function (fileItem, response, status, headers) {
            console.info('onCancelItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
        };
        uploader.onCompleteItem = function (fileItem, response, status, headers) {
            console.info('onCompleteItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
        };
        uploader.onCompleteAll = function () {
            console.info('onCompleteAll');
        };
        console.info('uploader', uploader);
        // -------------------------------
    }]);
```

Service:

```
messageBoardApp.factory('MessageBoardService', function () {
    var SaveMessage = function (newMessage) {
        alert(newMessage.content);
        alert(newMessage.title);
        return true;
    };
    return {
        SaveMessage: SaveMessage
    };
});
```

Module:

```
var messageBoardApp = angular.module("messageBoardApp", ['angularFileUpload']);
```

Am using below file-upload js from this link

```
https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/
```

I understand all the files which i have selected are in queue. Am not sure how to pass this files(more than 1) to .net mvc wep api call controller and then pass value to SQL DB.

Am stuck up with passing all the form values to service and then to wep api controller.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize your FileUploader you have to say to which url you would like to post your files. For example:

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new fileUploader({
      url: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + "/api/Upload/UploadFile"
    });
```